# Possible to control frame of a MovieClip that's in a Scroll Pane component?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a way to control the frames of a movieclip that's in the scroll pane component?

On my stage I've got four buttons setup.

I've got the following actionscript but get an error.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

scrollPane.source = pm_mc;
scrollPane.setSize(975, 500);
scrollPane.scrollDrag = true;

start_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
function start(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.pm_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
}

previous_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, previous);
function previous(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.pm_mc.prevFrame();
}

next_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, next);
function next(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.pm_mc.nextFrame();
}

end_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, end);
function end(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.pm_mc.gotoAndStop(31);
}

stop();
```

The errors I get are all the same:
Access of possibly undefined property pm_mc through a reference with static type fl.containers:ScrollPane

I'm still very much learning AS3.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to the movie clip as:

```
scrollPane.source.gotoAndStop(1);
```

So in your code:
Replace `scrollPane.pm_mc` with `scrollPane.source`.

**Update**
I guess I understand what you are trying to do now. You have a symbol in your library (which is not on your stage) and you want to create an instance of it and add it to the scrollPane. If I am right try this.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

scrollPane.source = new pm_mc();
scrollPane.setSize(975, 500);
scrollPane.scrollDrag = true;

start_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
function start(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.source.gotoAndStop(1);
}

previous_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, previous);
function previous(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.source.prevFrame();
}

next_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, next);
function next(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.source.nextFrame();
}

end_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, end);
function end(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.source.gotoAndStop(31);
}

stop();
```

Note the `new pm_mc()`. It creates an instance of the library symbol (a MovieClip).

Also you can refer to the scrollPane contents like this

```
((MovieClip)(scrollPane.content)).nextFrame();
```

Both the `content` and the `source` should work for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

When I add '...source.' I get an error saying "nextFrame is not a function" or "prevFrame is not a function" etc.

Any other hints?

Comment: @peeDee I tried it and it is working. Are you sure pm_mc is an instance of a MovieClip.

Comment: Hi danishgoel - pm_mc is being exported to AS from the library with an instance name of pm_mc.

The errors popup in the output upon clicking one of the buttons. The buttons are simple buttons if that weighs in at all.

Prior to clicking any buttons everything works as it should.

Comment: can you add a trace like this `trace(pm_mc);` and tell me the output.

Comment: I added the trace outside of all of the functions and in the output was [class pm_mc]

When the trace is added within one of the functions and that button is pressed nothing appears in the output with regards to the trace

Comment: @peeDee as I expected, When you export a symbol from your library for AS it ONLY exports the Symbol's class for instantiating the symbol, NOT the instance of the symbol on your stage. For this to work, either you should initialize the symbol in the AS file and use that, OR pass a reference of your stage symbol to AS code. It is not working because `pm_mc` is NOT an instance of `MovieClip` but is a `class` which NEEDS to be instantiated. Also is this code in your DocumentClass ?

Comment: I'm unsure of what your question is asking (is this code in your DocumentClass). Would you be able to reword in a simpler way for me?

What is involved in initializing the symbol in the AS file?

Comment: You are working in Flash IDE and the code above is in an ActionScript file. How is the AS file related to your flash project ? Is the file a [DocumentClass](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_document_class.html)

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are asking. The ActionScript is all in the first frame of my flash file. I'm not using any external AS files.

Comment: In that case either DO NOT export the symbol for AS in the symbol's properties OR give the instance on your stage a different name. You do have an instance of pm_mc on stage ? Or are you trying to create a new one in the code.

Comment: The only thing on my stage is the scroll pane. Currently pm_mc is just being added through actionscript.

Comment: @peeDee I have updated my answer and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help and patience. The updated answer works great.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting errors because you are getting movieclip from scrollPane in wrong way. check following code.

```
start_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
function start(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    (Object(scrollPane.content)).gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

i hope it will work...............

Comment: I wish I could select both as right answers but it won't let me. The other user had posted an answer first and spent a chunk of time correcting me.